# Constructing a basis for $\mathbb R_n[X]$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb R_n[X]$ be the vector space of reel polynomials of degree at most $n$. Let $P_0, \cdots, P_n$ be a family of polynomials such that $deg(P_i)=i$ for all $i=0..n$.
Show that this family is a basis of $\mathbb R_n[X]$.

My try:

Since dimension of $\mathbb R_n[X]$ is $n+1$ then it is enough to show that this family is independent.  We proceed by induction on $n$. It is clear that any non zero real is independent in $\mathbb R_0[X]$ the space of constant polynomials.

Now suppose that any family $P_0, \cdots, P_n$ of polynomials such that $deg(P_i)=i$ for all $i=0..n$.
 is a basis of $\mathbb R_n[X]$.

Take a family $Q_0, \cdots, Q_{n+1}$ of polynomials such that $deg(Q_i)=i$ for all $i=n$.
If $a_0Q_0+a_1Q_1+\cdots +a_{n+1}Q_{n+1}=0$ then $a_0Q_0-a_1Q_1-\cdots -a_nQ_n=-a_{n+1}Q_{n+1}$ then $a_{n+1}$ must be $0$, otherwise we would have that $deg(a_{n+1}Q_{n+1})=n+1$ while $deg(a_0Q_0-a_1Q_1-\cdots -a_nQ_n)\leq n$. Now the fact that $a_{n+1}=0$ implies that $a_0Q_0-a_1Q_1-\cdots -a_nQ_n=0$ hence $a_0=a_1=\cdots=a_n=0$ by induction hypothesis.

Is my try correct, thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes correct and nice!

Answer (score 2):

Your try is correct and nice.

Just for give you another method: let $a_0,a_1,\ldots, a_n\in\Bbb R$ such that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k P_k=0\tag{1}$$
and assume that the $a_k$ are not all $0$ so let $p$ the greatest integer such that $a_p\ne0$ hence the polynomial $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n a_k P_k$ has the degree $p$ which contradicts $(1)$.

Comment: The degree aragument works only because $deg(P_i)=i$ which garantees that there is no cancellation between coefficients of highest degrees , otherwise any family of $n+1$ polynomials would be a basis of $\mathbb R_n[X]$.